# Determine whether $(2 3 4 5)(2 4 6 7)$ is even or odd.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

Is the following permutation is even or odd?
$$(2 3 4 5)(2 4 6 7).$$

I have the feeling it is even. But how to explain it?

Comment: Look to which numbers the numbers $2,3,4,5,6,7$ are mapped to and determine the sign of the permutation

Answer (score 3):

Whatever parity a cycle of length $4$ has, you have composed two of them. Your permutation must therefore necessarily be even.

Answer (score 1):

If we are dealing with the composition of two cycles that both have length $n$ then both can be written as a composition of $n-1$ transpositions.

So the total number of transpositions is $2n-2$ hence is even, and that is enough to conclude that the composition is an even permutation.

Answer (score 0):

$$(2 3 4 5)\cdot(2 4 6 7)=(24)(32)(54)\cdot (26)(24)(67)$$ So it is an even permutation as it is product of $6$ (an even number) transpositions..

Comment: I don’t understany how did you get those pairs...